# Rxjs, best approach to wait and be notified for a property to be set?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to wait for a property to be set in an async way in one service, in order to execute things in another depending on this property.

Here is what i'm doing currently to solve this, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach with Rxjs or other ?

In this example I'm waiting for the property **_isInit** to be initialized and I'm using an `EventEmitter` in order to "notify" other services :

```
class OneService {

    private _isInit
    private _initStatus = new EventEmitter()

    constructor() {
        Promise.all([
            Promise1(), //async task
            Promise2(), //async task
        ])
        .then(res => {
            ... //doing stuff
            this.init() //stuff finished, OneService is initiated 
        })
    }

    init() {
        this._isInit = true
        this._initStatus.emit(this._isInit)
    }

    isInit() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            if (this._isInit)
                resolve()
            else {
                this._initStatus.subscribe(() => {
                     resolve()
                })
            } 
        }) 
     }
}

class anotherService {

    constructor(myService: OneService) {
        this.myService.isInit().then(() => {
            ... //doing stuff
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ReplaySubject like this:

```
class OneService {

    public valueStream = new ReplaySubject();

    constructor() {
        Promise.all([
            Promise1(), //async task
            Promise2(), //async task
        ])
        .then(res => {
            ... //doing stuff
            this.valueStream.next(value) 
        })
    }

 }

class anotherService {

    constructor(myService: OneService) {
        this.myService.valueStream.subscribe((value) => {
            ... //doing stuff
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe better to use a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) so you can start with a initialized=false value

Comment: Yep, could use a BehaviorSubject, but the init status may be a bit superfluous, eg. you know the service has initialised by nature of the fact that the stream has emitted a value.